# FileToText Class always generates this error "Cannot send headers; headers already sent in , line 0'"

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, docx, doc

I downloaded this php class **filetotext** here (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8908-PHP-Convert-DOCX-DOC-PDF-to-plain-text.html) which allows me to convert pdf and word into a php string that I can easily parse.
But it has this php function flush(); ob_flush(); in decodePDF() method which always generates this exception

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in , line 0' in C:\wamp\www\Jobs\trunk\library\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php on line 323

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See Abstract.php.Don`t use echo before set header.

Comment: I can't find any echo in that class...
The problem is the use of these php functions flush(); ob_flush(); 
The question is what can be the consequence if I remove both functions because everything seems OK without them